# Not able to delete a custom domain in azure front door

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-front-door

I have a custom domain associated with a front-end host in azure front door. I want to delete this domain association but getting a error which says "Please remove the DNS CNAME records and try again.". Why am I getting this error. Does this mean I need to remove CNAME record from my domain provider? If it is so, it will be problematic in CI/CD pipeline.
Attaching screenshot of the error.

[image]

Comment: If you don't delete the `CNAME` record, your domain still points towards a Front Door that's no longer associated to that domain. So yes, first delete the DNS record, then remove the domain from Front Door. You state "_it will be problematic in CI/CD pipeline_", but removing custom domains in a CI/CD pipeline (so on a regular basis) doesn't feel like a constructive solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this [issue #11231 in GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11231). Looks like they have introduced this breaking change recently. But it seems like it can be disabled by registering feature flag according to comment from the issue:

```
az feature register --namespace Microsoft.Network --name BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion
```

But be aware that it's subscription level.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime they changed the namespace to `Microsoft.Cdn`

```bash
az feature register --namespace Microsoft.Cdn --name BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion
```

Comment: In other words, this answer is valid if you are using `cdn` rather than `frontdoor` - Thanks ! :)