# How to delete a Front Door resource locked by a domain I don't own

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-front-door

Azure Front Door does not allow frontend endpoint deletion if the endpoint's domain still points to the Front Door using a CNAME record. The same holds even when there is just the verification domain (afdverify).

> 409 Conflict
> Cannot delete frontend endpoint "www.example.com" because it is still directly or indirectly (using "afdverify" prefix) CNAMEd to front door "example.azurefd.net". Please remove the DNS CNAME records and try again.

While I hate that there is no way to delete such a frontend, there is a way to deal with that even if the DNS zone cannot be changed by the Front Door owner -- just don't assign the frontend endpoint to any routing rule and don't mind it; it consumes just a bit of developer's attention, which makes it somewhat bearable.

The problem comes with the fact that such a frontend prevents even the deletion of the whole Front Door, which in turn prevents deletion of the whole resource group.

Why is that a problem? Consider that a single subscription is shared by the whole dev team and someone creates a Front Door instance for experiments, uses his own domain and later leaves the team. Now the resource consumes money as there has to be at least one routing rule for the default frontend endpoint and routing rules are paid per time unit, and there is no obvious way to get rid of it.

Is there a way to delete such a Front Door instance besides contacting Microsoft support or asking the owner of the domain to pretty please delete the records pointing to the Front Door?

Comment: I would look into policy to prevent people using any domain if this is an issue with your team. Other i wold create temp subscription and set budget to 1 dollar and move such resources there so they dont waste your money.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am not familiar with Azure Policy, but I've heard about it and will look into how it could help us. As far as I know, Front Door resource cannot be moved across subscriptions -- but I might be wrong and I will look into it once more.

Comment: Had a look at budgets and their scopes. They can be set on resource group level, too. It seems budgets are notification mechanisms that may have automation attached, but I have no idea how they could be used to actually limit the cost of the resource group in this case. The examples talk about stopping virtual machines, but there is no way to stop Front Door.

Comment: Found a similar Q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67306267/2157640

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had the same issue. While checking the Microsoft documentation we found that Microsoft has introduced this breaking change ([Terraform provider for ARM issue #11231](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11231)).

But it seems like the CNAME check can be disabled for a subscription via Azure CLI [`az feature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/feature?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
az feature register --namespace Microsoft.Network --name BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion
```

First, run the above command and then go to the Front Door resource and try deleting it.

If you need to enable the CNAME check again:

```
az feature unregister --namespace Microsoft.Network --name BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion
```

If you need to check the status of the feature:

```
az feature list -o table --query "[?contains(name, 'Microsoft.Network/BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion')].{Name:name,State:properties.state}"
```

Comment: It seems that changing `register` to `unregister` should revert the effect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/feature?view=azure-cli-latest
Also, I found that this is the way to check the status of the feature registration: `az feature list -o table --query "[?contains(name, 'Microsoft.Network/BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion')].{Name:name,State:properties.state}"`

Comment: By 11231, you mean this Terraform issue? https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11231

Comment: Apologies for the unclear answer. I was referring to the Terraform issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11231

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to include the related info we discussed here. Feel free to [edit] further.

Comment: Even though I registered the `BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion` feature, I couldn't delete the Custom Domain through either the portal or the CLI. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: In Azure PS, the cmdlets are [Get-AzProviderFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azproviderfeature?view=azps-11.3.0), [Register-AzProviderFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/register-azproviderfeature?view=azps-11.3.0), and [Unregister-AzProviderFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/unregister-azproviderfeature?view=azps-11.3.0). `Register-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName "BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion" -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.Network"`

Answer (score 6):

On 5th April 2021 I received email from Microsoft that  a following change was introduced in Azure:

> On 9 April 2021, we're updating Azure Front Door and Content Delivery Network to help prevent dangling DNS entries and the security risks they create. At that time, we'll start requiring the removal of canonical name (CNAME) records for Azure Front Door and Content Delivery Network resource endpoints from DNS before the resources can be deleted.
>
> To delete Azure Front Door or Content Delivery Network resources, you must first remove the resource endpoint CNAME records from DNS starting on 9 April 2021.
>
> If you have questions, get answers from community experts in Microsoft Q&A. If you have a support plan and you need technical help, please create a support request.

If you do not own that domain at all the best you can do is to contact Microsoft through Support Plan or your CSP provider and ask for deletion or removal of the domain from your front door instance.

Comment: I've found very similar wording in the tutorial for adding custom domain to Front Door on MS Docs, in the ["Clean up resources" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain#clean-up-resources). `To prevent dangling DNS entries and the security risks they create, starting from April 9th 2021, Azure Front Door requires removal of the CNAME records to Front Door endpoints before the resources can be deleted. Resources include Front Door custom domains, Front Door endpoints or Azure resource groups that has Front Door custom domain(s) enabled.`

Comment: The same constraint is applied to custom domains of CDN and probably elsewhere too.

Comment: @Palec + Miq... Thank you so much! This was exactly my issue for my storage account with a static website and CDN. I couldn't delete the CDN without first removing the CNAME records from my registrar.  The initial issue was caused because you can only use a wildcard certificate on one and only one CDN domain endpoint. We had already used that certificate once! So to solve, purchase a separate certificate for each subdomain or use the Microsoft managed certificates.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-wildcard-domain

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, but it was fixed. like this
recreate dns zone, add CNAME record for it. Like in your case
afdverify.example.com CNAME , then go frontdoor resource, delete it.
I think so it will helps to you

Comment: This fixed for me too. To clarify, the reason I could not delete the front door was because the afdverify CNAME pointing to anything was missing. I *added* a CNAME record:
afdverify -> anything.com
After waiting a few minutes, I was able to delete the front door. The FD delete error message is misleading.